# Convert CanvasRenderTarget to ImageSource in WinUI

Tags: .net, maui, winui-3, .net-maui, maui-windows

I'm working on .Net MAUI and I used native rendering in my application. So for Windows (WinUi-3), I have drawings rendered on the CanvasRenderTarget object and now I have to provide this as ImageSource(MAUI) to the user.

I tried to get Pixels from canvasrendertarget object and later to the stream source. But setting this stream source to the Image control, I'm not able to get the image output.

```
             renderTarget = new CanvasRenderTarget(CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice(),(float) 400, (float)400, 96);
             using (var ds = renderTarget.CreateDrawingSession())
             {     
                ds.FillCircle(10, 10, 400, Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(250, 140, 120, 150));
             }
    
             byte[] bytes = renderTarget.GetPixelBytes();

            //Setting the Stream source to my Image control
            imageview.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bytes));
```

Not sure what I'm missing, how can I convert WinUi RenderTarget object to MAUI.ImageSource ?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create an `ImageSource` from raw pixel data, however `FromStream` expects an encoded PNG or JPG image instead.

To be able to achieve this, you will need to encode that raw pixel data first - luckily there is already an implementation for doing so in `Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder`.

Here is a working version of your code snippet, where we create a `BitmapEncoder` that will convert pixel data to a PNG image. Then, it's just a matter of calling `SetPixelData` with the appropriate parameters to generate said image:

```csharp
            var renderTarget = new CanvasRenderTarget(CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice(), (float)400, (float)400, 96);

            using (var ds = renderTarget.CreateDrawingSession())
            {
                ds.FillCircle(10, 10, 400, Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(250, 140, 120, 150));
            }

            byte[] bytes = renderTarget.GetPixelBytes();

            var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8 , BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, 400, 400, 96, 96, bytes);
            await encoder.FlushAsync();

            //Setting the Stream source to my Image control
            imageview.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream.AsStream());
```

Comment: Thanks, but still no Image is visible when setting this source to my image control.

Comment: The above code was tested on a fresh Maui project (RC 6.0.300) and can confirm it was working. Perhaps you could provide a repro project to try and diagnose it?

Comment: Thanks @r2d2rigo , But when I  tried the same sample above and it doesn't work. I have checked converting the local assembly file to ensure my image control and it was working fine.